# JSSOR slider not resizing properly in iOS when rotating device orientation

Tags: jquery, ios, resize, device-orientation, jssor

I'm designing a responsive site and using a jssor slider. The slider is responsive and works well with the following in the head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width>
```

When I edit this snippet, as below, the slider does not resize properly in iOS when rotating the device from landscape to portrait (and vice versa):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I'm trying to prevent iOS from zooming in while in landscape.

You can see an example of this problem when opening [this page](http://acstudyabroad.org/01Temp_Slider.html) on an iOS device or simulator and changing the device orientation back and forth. The slider opens/loads properly in both landscape and portrait. The problem is only when the device is rotated.

This is the portion of the script that controls the resize/responsiveness:

```
$JssorSlider$("slider2_container", options);
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_slider2.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider2.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 1024));
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }

        ScaleSlider();
        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please handle orientationchange event

```
    function ScaleSlider() {
        var parentWidth = jssor_slider2.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
        if (parentWidth)
            jssor_slider2.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 1024));
        else
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }

    ScaleSlider();
    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
```